# Prove that a set $U \subset M$ is open if and only if none of its points are limits of it's complement

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

I just completed this exercise from Pugh and would like to double-check that my proof holds:

Theorem 5:

> Openess is dual to closedness: The complement of an open set is a closed set and the complement of a closed set is an open set

> Prove that a set $U \subset M$ is open if and only if none of its points are limits of it's complement

Pf: Assume $U \subset M$ is open. Now assume for contradiction that there exists $x \in U$ that is a limit of $U^{c}$. By Theorem 5 $U^{c}$ is closed so we have reached our contradiction
Now assume $x \in U$ then $ x \notin \lim U^{c}$. We want to show $U$ is open. We know $M = U \cup U^{c}$ so by hypothesis all $x \in \lim U^{c}$ implies $x \in U^{c}$ so $U^{c}$ is closed so by Theorem 5 $U \subset M$ is open.

Comment: Please tell us what Theorem 5 says!

Comment: Added. Sorry about that

Comment: Your proof works

Comment: I think the first part would be clearer if you said "Since $U^c$ is closed, $x \in U^c$" making the contradiction explicit. But as long as that is your reason, that part is correct. The second part should be "assume that *if* $x \in U$ then $x \notin \lim U^c$." The main content of the proof is correct.

Comment: What are the limits of a set?

Comment: Thank you prefered_anon

Comment: @WilliamElliot The same thing as a limit point I believe